# Confused about mac shortcut "option + /"

Tags: google-sheets

There should be the keyboard shortcut "option + /" on mac to open the help menu in google sheets. However, when I press the keyboard combination (to be exact i press the option/^ key  plus the 7 key where the slash is) nothing happens. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an international keyboard, and some keyboard shortcuts that use keys like `/` will not work because of differing key locations in the keyboard. On a Mac, press **Ctrl + ⌥** to open the **Help** menu, then press **arrow down**  to enter the **Search the menus** field.